# How to use dataframe inside an udf and parse the data in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala and spark. I have a requirement to create the new dataframe by using the udf.
I have a 2 dataframes, one contains 3 columns namely company, id, and type.
df2 contains 2 columns namely company and message.
df2 JSON will be like this

```
{"company": "Honda", "message": ["19:[\"cost 500k\"],[\"colour blue\"]","20:[\"cost 600k\"],[\"colour white\"]"]}
{"company": "BMW", "message": ["19:[\"cost 1500k\"],[\"colour blue\"]"]}
```

df2 will be like this:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|company|             message|
+-------+--------------------+
|  Honda|[19:["cost 500k"]...|
|    BMW|[19:["cost 1500k"...|
+-------+--------------------+
 |-- company: string (nullable = true)
 |-- message: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

df1 will be like this:

```
+----------+---+-------+
|company   | id|   name|
+----------+---+-------+
|  Honda   | 19| city  |
|  Honda   | 20| amaze |
|  BMW     | 19| x1    |
+----------+---+-------+
```

I want to create a new data frame by replacing the id in df2 with the name in df1.

```
["city:[\"cost 500k\"],[\"colour blue\"]","amaze:[\"cost 600k\"],[\"colour white\"]"]
```

I had tried with udf by passing message as Seq[String] and company but I was not able to select the data in df1.
I want the output like this:

```
+-------+----------------------+
|company|             message  |
+-------+----------------------+
|  Honda|[city:["cost 500k"]...|
|    BMW|[x1:["cost 1500k"...  |
+-------+----------------------+
```

I tried by using the fallowing udf but I was facing errors while selecting the name

```
def asdf(categories: Seq[String]):String={
     | var data=""
     | for(w<-categories){
     | if (w != null){
     | var id=w.toString().indexOf(":")
     | var namea=df1.select("name").where($"id" === 20).map(_.getString(0)).collect()
     | var name=namea(0)
     | println(name)
     | var ids=w.toString().substring(0,id)
     | var li=w.toString().replace(ids,name)
     | println(li)
     | data=data+li
     | }
     | }
     | data
     | }
```

Comment: can you post output you want ?

Comment: I want to create a new dataframe with two columns having one column as company and another column having the message like this ["city:[\"cost 500k\"],[\"colour blue\"]","amaze:[\"cost 600k\"],[\"colour white\"]"]

Comment: is this ```message``` contains valid json data ??

Comment: yes It is valid JSON data
{
"company": "Honda",
"message": [
"19:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"]",
"20:["cost 600k"],["colour white"]"
]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code.

```
scala> df1.show(false)
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|company|message                                                              |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Honda  |[19:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"], 20:["cost 600k"],["colour white"]]|
|BMW    |[19:["cost 1500k"],["colour blue"]]                                  |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df2.show(false)
+-------+---+-----+
|company|id |name |
+-------+---+-----+
|Honda  | 19|city |
|Honda  | 20|amaze|
|BMW    | 19|x1   |
+-------+---+-----+
```

```
val replaceFirst = udf((message: String,id:String,name:String) => 
  if(message.contains(s"""${id}:""")) message.replaceFirst(s"""${id}:""",s"${name}:") else ""
)
```

```
val jdf = 
df1
.withColumn("message",explode($"message"))
.join(df2,df1("company") === df2("company"),"inner")
.withColumn(
    "message_data",
    replaceFirst($"message",trim($"id"),$"name")
)
.filter($"message_data" =!= "")
```

```
scala> jdf.show(false)

+-------+---------------------------------+-------+---+-----+------------------------------------+
|company|message                          |company|id |name |message_data                        |
+-------+---------------------------------+-------+---+-----+------------------------------------+
|Honda  |19:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"] |Honda  | 19|city |city:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"]  |
|Honda  |20:["cost 600k"],["colour white"]|Honda  | 20|amaze|amaze:["cost 600k"],["colour white"]|
|BMW    |19:["cost 1500k"],["colour blue"]|BMW    | 19|x1   |x1:["cost 1500k"],["colour blue"]   |
+-------+---------------------------------+-------+---+-----+------------------------------------+
```

```
scala> df1.join(df2,df1("company") === df2("company"),"inner").select(df1("company"),df1("message"),df2("id"),df2("name")).withColumn("message",explode($"message")).withColumn("message",replaceFirst($"message",trim($"id"),$"name")).filter($"message" =!= "").groupBy($"company").agg(collect_list($"message").cast("string").as("message")).show(false)
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|company|message                                                                   |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Honda  |[amaze:["cost 600k"],["colour white"], city:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"]]|
|BMW    |[x1:["cost 1500k"],["colour blue"]]                                       |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Here you are exploding the message so it was converting to 2 rows for the same company Honda. Instead, I need to get whole into a single row like this:
city:["cost 500k"],["colour blue"],amaze:["cost 600k"],["colour white"]